# Flutter Camera: Black Preview after switching cameras/reinitialising CameraController

Tags: flutter

I'm experimenting with flutter_camera. I'm trying to add a camera switch like this:

```
CameraController? controller;
bool frontCamera = false;

@override
void initState() {
  initCamera();
  super.initState();
}

initCamera() {
  if (controller?.value.isInitialized ?? false) {
    controller!.dispose();
  }
  controller = CameraController(
      cameras.firstWhere(
        (element) => element.lensDirection == (frontCamera ? CameraLensDirection.front : CameraLensDirection.back),
      ),
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: false);
  controller!.initialize().then((value) {
    setState(() {});
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Camera Test")),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        if (controller != null)
          Container(
            child: CameraPreview(controller!),
            height: 400,
          ),
        Row(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                frontCamera = !frontCamera;
                initCamera();
              },
              child: Text("Switch"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

When the first `initCamera` call works as expected and my camera preview is rendered. When I press the "Switch" Button, the `initCamera` method is called and the CameraPreview is re-build but it just renders a black preview. I don't an Error or a helpful debug log.

Any ideas?